# Trouble setting up Google Analytics for website that contains query string

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to create a new tracking code for a new web property in GA however the URL contains a query string at the end of it. The URL string contains common information except for the query string at the end of it.

For example:

http://www.website.com/login.aspx?p=abc

http://www.website.com/login.aspx?p=def

http://www.website.com/login.aspx?p=ghi

GA will not allow me to create a unique tracking code for each of these sites since they contain the query string. So if I remove it, how will I track each of these as unique web sites in GA?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem by creating 3 separate views with a filter for each view, that only records the traffic for the right URL.

First you have to extract the value after the last "/" with this code:

```
function() {
    var loginURL = window.location.href.split("/")[3];
    return loginURL;
}
```

- Put that value into a custom dimension (with GTM just use a custom javascript variable, with GA refer to [this documentaion](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) on how to set a custom dimension).
- Set up a filter in your new Google Analytics view that only includes traffic with the value of the custom dimension being "login.aspx?p=abc".